# Install Ubuntu with windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I need to install ubuntu alongside with my current version of Windows in my new computer
(I prefer UBUNTU but I still need windows to run some programs in my work place).

The point is that, in windows 8 I can not access BIOS as I did the first time that I installed ubuntu in my older computer.

Can somebody please provide me a detailed information about how to install Ubuntu without corrupting Windows 8

Thanks people.

Luis

Comment: You don't access BIOS from Windows 8. Bios is accessed when you just switched your pc on, probably by pressing `[Del]`, `[F2]` or `[F10]`. You can also install Ubuntu inside Windows (no need to do anything in the BIOS), but I never did it, so I don't know how that works.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered doing this in a virtual machine? It is a very good way to get familiar with Linux until you are ready to do something like a dual boot. It also eliminates the need for you to reboot your machine to get to the other OS.

Some options you have to do this:

[VMware Player download](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)

[Virtualbox download](https://www.virtualbox.org)

These are both free, and they allow you to install an entire OS inside a virtual machine.

If you look at the screenshot I have attached, you can see on the right half of the screen that I am running VMware Workstation, and I have several VMs installed. I have Windows 8 installed in a VM and it is active. The arrows point to some of the VMs that I have installed on this machine.

[image: Virtualization example]

I am doing what I am suggesting to you, but in the opposite direction. I am working on a Linux OS for the host, and running Windows (and several other OSes) as a guest.

If you have any questions on how to get this working, let me know.

One thing to note - I've listed the free solutions. The "Workstation" version of VMware that I use, that has a paid license, but you can use it in trial mode for some period of time.

Comment: Interesting. Why the downvote?